# Delete random numbers from link with 301 redirect nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, wordpress

I have to delete a random numbers from permalink structure of my site working on nginx server by mask:
`DOMAIN.COM/YEAR/postname/RANDOM_NUMBERS/` → `DOMAIN.COM/YEAR/postname/`

I've tried something like this wirhout succsess

```
rewrite ^/([0-9]{4})/(.*)$/[0-9]+ ^/$4/$2/ permanent;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rewrite "^(/[0-9]{4}/.*/)[0-9]+/"  $1  permanent;
```

and since [0-9] = \d, plus your extra requirement of at least two digits, and if "postname" can't be a directory structure,

```
rewrite "^(/\d{4}/[^/]+/)\d{2,}/"  $1 permanent;
```

Comment: Thank you! I've also have to add double quotes because of curly braces: `rewrite "^(/[0-9]{4}/.*/)[0-9][0-9]+/" $1 permanent;` (Changed `[0-9]+[0-9]+` instead of `[0-9]+` so if post is paged (less than 10 pages) this rule do not redirect it).

Comment: My second solution is more appropriate then.